# List subpages in order

Tags: child-pages

This may be a very basic question, but I'm a beginner. How can I list my subpages in alphabetical order? I have 14 subpages total.

This is what I was told to use but my page is a mess.

```
[subpages page=27 items=12 order=alphabetical desc]
```

Comment: that code is a shortcode that dosen't come in Wordpress, so it have to be from a plugin or theme. Can you tell us which one?

Answer (score 1):

get a list of sub pages using `wp_list_pages();` function for more information visit [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)

```
$args = array('child_of' => 27);

wp_list_pages( $args );
```

this will print a list of sub pages (child) of page 27, sort alphabetically order, also you can get a list of sub pages by doing this another way like below.

```
wp_list_pages( 'child_of=27' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in your theme to get it. For more information visit [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages).

```
<?php
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'sort_column' => 'post_title' ) );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
        continue;

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
?>
    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
    <div class="entry"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
<?php
}   
?>
```